# Salesforce Unknown property 'String.Name'

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I want to list the Result of Survey From tables, but I am getting error

> Unknown property 'String.Name'

I need to show the result on VisualForce page.

VF page

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false"  controller="SurveyResultController">
<apex:form>
   <apex:pageBlock title="Submited Result">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SurveyResult}" var="sr">
            <apex:column value="{!sr.Name}"/>            
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form>
```

Apex Controller

```apex
public with sharing class SurveyResultController {
    public String surveyId {
        get;
        set{
            this.surveyId = value;
        }
    }
    public Integer SurveySessionID {
        get;
        set{
            this.SurveySessionID = value;
        }
    }
    public String ssessionid {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public SurveyResultController() {
        surveyId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        ssessionid = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ssessionid');
    }
    public List<String> getSurveyResult() {
        List<tblSurveyResult__c> qr = [SELECT Name,
                                              QuestionID__c,
                                              SurveyID__c,
                                              Answer__c,
                                              QuestionID__r.Id,
                                              QuestionID__r.Name,
                                              QuestionID__r.Question__c,
                                              QuestionID__r.SelectedAnswer__c
                                        FROM tblSurveyResult__c
                                        WHERE SurveyID__c = :surveyId
                                          AND SurveySessionID__c = :SurveySessionID];
        List<String> resp = new List<String>();
        for (tblSurveyResult__c r : qr) {
            resp.add(r.Name);
        }

        return resp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the following line

```
<apex:column value="{!sr.Name}"/>
```

you try to read `Name` from String entity.

In the controller you prepared a `List<String>` and return it to the page.

```
    List<String> resp = new List<String>();
    for (tblSurveyResult__c r : qr) {
        resp.add(r.Name);
    }

    return resp;
```

So, your options:

1. Use the following format on the page

   ```
   <apex:column value="{!sr}"/>
   ```
2. return list of tblSurveyResult__c to the page

   ```
   public List<tblSurveyResult__c > getSurveyResult() {
       return [SELECT Name,
                      QuestionID__c,
                      SurveyID__c,
                      Answer__c,
                      QuestionID__r.Id,
                      QuestionID__r.Name,
                      QuestionID__r.Question__c,
                      QuestionID__r.SelectedAnswer__c
               FROM tblSurveyResult__c
               WHERE SurveyID__c = :surveyId
                 AND SurveySessionID__c :SurveySessionID];

   }
   ```

**EDIT due to your comments please use the second option**

Return list of tblSurveyResult__c to the page

```apex
 public List<tblSurveyResult__c > getSurveyResult() {
        return [SELECT Name,
                       QuestionID__c,
                       SurveyID__c,
                       Answer__c,
                       QuestionID__r.Id,
                       QuestionID__r.Name,
                       QuestionID__r.Question__c,
                       QuestionID__r.SelectedAnswer__c
                FROM tblSurveyResult__c
                WHERE SurveyID__c = :surveyId
                  AND SurveySessionID__c :SurveySessionID];

  }




 <apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false"  controller="SurveyResultController">
<apex:form>
   <apex:pageBlock title="Submited Result">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SurveyResult}" var="sr">
            <apex:column value="{!sr.SurveyID__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!sr.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!sr.QuestionID__r.Question__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!sr.QuestionID__r.SelectedAnswer__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: I have replaced the controller and now my VF page is like : 

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SurveyResult}" var="sr">
             <apex:column value="{!sr}" headerValue="Name"/>
             <apex:column value="{!sr.QuestionID__r.Name}" headerValue="Question"/>              
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
Still im not getting the results , i want to show the other fields aswell like 'Question Name', 'Answered Question' etc.

Comment: Actually i m not sure how to access the other fields value in VF page.

Comment: i have updated VF section of the answer, still results are not displaying on VF page, there are three records in the database when i query in SoqlXplorer.

Comment: Now the issue is when in debug log it shows. 
WHERE (SurveyID__c = :tmpVar1 AND SurveySessionID__c = :tmpVar2)

i am not sure why 'tmpVar1' and 'tmpVar1' instead of 'surveyId' and 'SurveySessionID' , and if i hardcode these values it works perfectly.

Comment: @AdilShah please do not try to edit my answer with your new details in issue. Add all these details to your question.

Comment: @AdilShah `tmpVar` is not an issue, it's internal sf representation of your variables in a query. In order to be sure that VF page is okay you can remove `WHERE SurveyID__c = :surveyId
              AND SurveySessionID__c :SurveySessionID];` from your query for a test. I see that your query doesn't return rows with data. So, now the issue is in the query

Comment: Yes everything else works fine if  i removes WHERE clause , it return rows. issue is in `SurveySessionID__c :SurveySessionID` @pavel Slepiankou

Comment: @AdilShah how do you set `SurveySessionID`?